# The IMAP server did not accept the username and/or password: A0001 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] I

Tags: bounce-processing

Bouncing & Activity-to-Contact mailings.

Recently we started getting the infamous

> "An error occured while sending or receiving mail. The IMAP server did
> not accept the username and/or password: A0001 NO
> [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure). (See log for
> more details."

followed by api4 exceptions thrown:

> throw new CRM_Core_Exception(ts('Could not find valid value for %1',
> [1 => $name]));

this happens on two different CiviCRM 5.50 projects simultaneously, each project has  different external mail server providers ( gmail and office365 ) so it seems quite unlikely both Google and Microsoft decided to kick us off.
The common thing in both setups is the recent CiviCRM 5.50x update so I wonder if this is the key - however, if this was the case someone would already reported it here.

Does anyone else have the same issue recently?

Comment: Yes, have the same issue.  Recently upgraded to 5.51.3